# What does "First Class" refer to in X-Men: First Class?

Tags: title, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-first-class

I am confused and curious about the meaning of "First Class" in *X-Men: First Class*. What does it refer to?

Answer (score 57):

They're the "first class" of Xavier's school for gifted youngsters, as well as the "first class" of the X-Men.

With regards to the title being some sort of pun intended to denote the characters as "high quality", I'm going to argue that it's not and is simply intended to indicate they are the first class of both Charles' school and the X-Men.

From the section on the [film's development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men:_First_Class#Development) on Wikipedia:

> As producer Simon Kinberg read the comic series **X-Men: First Class**, he
>   suggested studio 20th Century Fox to adapt it. Kinberg, however, did
>   not want to follow the comic too much, as he felt "it was not fresh
>   enough in terms of storytelling", considering them too similar to
>   Twilight and John Hughes movies, and also because the producers wanted
>   an adaptation that would introduce new characters. Both Kinberg and
>   Shuler Donner said that they wanted characters with visuals and powers
>   that had not been seen and that worked well as an ensemble, even if
>   they did not work together in the comics. Shuler Donner later said
>   that the original idea was to green-light First Class depending on the
>   success of X-Men Origins: Magneto. That project was seeking
>   approval to film in Washington, D.C., and by December 2008, Goyer said
>   filming would begin if X-Men Origins: Wolverine was successful. The
>   story was moved forward to 1962, and involves Xavier and Magneto
>   battling a villain.

Given they're also referencing the previously intended Origins series of the X-Men franchise, this would further indicate that "first class" is merely intended to convey that the cast of characters involved are merely the first X-Men.

[Additional research](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/X-Men_First_Class_Vol_1) on the comic series X-Men: First Class mentioned in the excerpt would indicate that the comic follows the early adventures of the very first X-Men team.

As such, the title of the movie shares its name with the title of a short run comic series, which was designed to detail the exploits of the "first class" of the X-Men team. Any inference of the term "first class" to indicate a high level of quality would therefore seem to be either inaccurate, personal interpretation, or both, but certainly not an intended pun.

Comment: Isn't there "class one" etc of mutant's power classification? Any information if the title is referring to that?

Comment: No. Only the films use numeration to classify mutant powers and when this notion is first introduced in 'The Last Stand', Castillo states that Magneto (and Pyro) are the only mutants in the room above 'Class 3' (it is later stated that Jean is the only 'Class 5' mutant they have ever come across so its a safe assumption that Eric and John are 'Class 4'). Eric is clearly a central member of the 'First Class' in Vaughn's film so MattD's answer is absolutely correct.

Comment: You've just used “first class” twice in the answer, without explaining either time what the phrase means.

Comment: I figured this answer was to be taken literally as in they are the first class as supposed to the second.

Comment: What's necessary to explain what "first class" means? Some appear to be taking it as a pun, but I honestly don't see it as much of a pun. They go to a school for mutants that also happens to end up being the home of the X-Men, so they're the "first class" of students at the school and thus the "first class" of X-Men. Given how hodgepodge they are as a team, I'd hardly infer it's meant to refer to them as "high quality". They're very much rough around the edges.

Comment: @MattD Imagine someone doesn't understand English very well (which may well include the OP). That is, they don't understand properly what the words “first” and “class” mean. Now, you explain “first class” by saying _the "first class" of Xavier's school for gifted youngsters_ — which is better than nothing, but still not maximally helpful. Why not explain it using different words? (For example: among the batches of students at the school, they were the earliest one. Or whatever you prefer.) Imagine a dictionary: generally we try to define a word using *other* words, not the word itself.

Comment: @MattD Why are you contradicting yourself now? You [already said it was obvious](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/86198/what-does-first-class-refer-to-in-x-men-first-class/86211#comment146979_86211)

Comment: @Michael Because upon further research, it would appear that's not the case.

Comment: I have a hard time believing that the producers either of the movie or of the comic series could have missed the double entendre of "first class" meaning both "initial group of students" and "best".  I think you've shown definitely that they intended the "group of students" meaning, but there's nowhere near enough data here to assert "certainly not an intended pun".  At most you can say "I find no sources confirming that the pun was intentional." I agree that this answer would be much improved by moving the possible definitions to the top instead of repeating "first class" with no definition.

Answer (score 50):

It's a pun.

['First-class' as in 'excellent' or 'high quality'](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/first-class), and "first class" as in they are the initial group of students.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's basically the same that [MattD's answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/86199/40515) (most voted at the time of writing this) but this one actually explains the different meanings. Also, it explicitely states that it's a play on words.

Comment: I don't directly point out that it's a pun or play on words, but I figured my use of quotes around "first class" made that obvious.

Comment: It's not a pun.  They are the first class of X-Men.

Comment: @Michael Can you provide anything to support that claim?  A line from the movie?  A statement from the director/writer/cast member?  The movie was about the first class of X-Men that Xavier trained.  There's no pun there.  You simply stating it doesn't make it so. X-Men Origins: Wolverine is about the origin of the X-Man known as Wolverine.  Me saying that it's a pun meaning Wolverine is more original than the other X-Men doesn't make that the case either

Comment: @Kevin ... do you have any evidence to support that it wasn't intended to be a pun?  Its a reasonable interpretation that isn't really much of a stretch of imagination, and with no corroborating evidence one way or another, its a reasonable answer for this site for us to vote up or down.

Comment: @iandotkelly It is generally considered good question form on most, if not all, stack exchange sites to provide some sort of citation/evidence for an answer.  The onus of evidence is on the one providing the answer.  Furthermore, it's not, in my opinion, a reasonable interpretation.  A pun is a joke based on a play on words. Where is the joke?  If this was a parody and the "heroes" were all losers or something, calling it a punt might make sense.  As is, it's just some coincidence in the words possible meanings that Michael noticed

Comment: @Kevin I would always encourage someone to include references, quotations from the movie or from writers and directors - but you and I are going to have to disagree with the reasonableness of an interpretation that it was intended as a pun.  It was my interpretation as well.  Yeah, its a mild joke, hardly side splitting - a play on words that it means both a class of students and that they are the best

Comment: The dictionary definitions of the phrase "first class" emphasize quality and eliteness, the definition that they are the chronological first set of students is usually missing - but of course that was intended in the meaning as well, but you don't question that part of the interpretation.

Comment: "It was my interpretation as well" and "the interpretation is reasonable" are not the same thing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ... I agree.  But the standard dictionary definitions of the phrase supports that it is a reasonable interpretation.  It may not be correct, but it is reasonable.

Comment: @iandotkelly: I'm not convinced that the dictionary definition of "pun" supports it, but on that question I shall withhold a strong opinion :P

Comment: Absolutely not a pun, at all. They are the "first class" of Xavier's School for Gifted Youngsters.

Comment: @iandotkelly You assume that it was meant to be taken as a phrase, not as individual words. The definition of each word, "first" "class", would indicate it is simply the initial group of students to become X-Men. In addition, if it were meant to be a phrase, it would most likely be written as "first-class", not "first class", as shown here: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/first-class

Comment: This answer seems more frrom the standpoint of view of a english teacher than a connaisseur of X-Men